# Summing duplicate keys when trying to spread() in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm trying to learn R, and I decided to figure it out by building a thing to read the live election results that my state puts up on election night. Unfortunately, I've hit a snag in computing a `Margin` value to use for map fills. My state (WA) uses a Top 2 primary, which means that in some races there are two people of the same party in the November election. That's probably too much background, but anyway here's the coding problem:

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Dist    Party                       Votes
1       (Prefers Democratic Party)  124151
1       (Prefers Republican Party)  101428
2       (Prefers Democratic Party)  122173
2       (Prefers Republican Party)  79518
3       (Prefers Republican Party)  124796
3       (Prefers Democratic Party)  78018
4       (Prefers Republican Party)  75307
4       (Prefers Republican Party)  77772
5       (Prefers Republican Party)  135470
5       (Prefers Democratic Party)  87772
6       (Prefers Democratic Party)  141265
6       (Prefers Republican Party)  83025
7       (Prefers Democratic Party)  203954
7       (Prefers Republican Party)  47921
8       (Prefers Republican Party)  125741
8       (Prefers Democratic Party)  73003
9       (Prefers Democratic Party)  118132
9       (Prefers Republican Party)  48662
10      (Prefers Democratic Party)  99279
10      (Prefers Republican Party)  82213
```

And I want to make it look like this:

```
Dist    (Prefers Democratic Party)  (Prefers Republican Party)
1       124151                      101428
2       122173                      79518
3       78018                       124796
4       [NA or 0]                   153079
5       87772                       135470
6       141265                      83025
7       203954                      47921
8       73003                       125741
9       118132                      48662
10      99279                       82213
```

`spread()` doesn't work because of the duplicates in `Dist = 4`. I've managed to put this together from some other questions on here, but I'm not satisfied with it and I'm almost positive there's a better way

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

CongressTidy %>%
  group_by(Dist) %>%
  mutate(GOPVotes = sum(ifelse(Party == "(Prefers Republican Party)", Votes, 0))) %>%
  mutate(DemVotes = sum(ifelse(Party == "(Prefers Democratic Party)", Votes, 0)))
```

That returns this:

```
Dist    Party                       Votes   GOPVotes    DemVotes
<fctr>  <fctr>                      <int>   <dbl>       <dbl>
1       (Prefers Democratic Party)  124151  101428      124151
1       (Prefers Republican Party)  101428  101428      124151
2       (Prefers Democratic Party)  122173  79518       122173
2       (Prefers Republican Party)  79518   79518       122173
3       (Prefers Republican Party)  124796  124796      78018
3       (Prefers Democratic Party)  78018   124796      78018
4       (Prefers Republican Party)  75307   153079      0
4       (Prefers Republican Party)  77772   153079      0
5       (Prefers Republican Party)  135470  135470      87772
5       (Prefers Democratic Party)  87772   135470      87772
6       (Prefers Democratic Party)  141265  83025       141265
6       (Prefers Republican Party)  83025   83025       141265
7       (Prefers Democratic Party)  203954  47921       203954
7       (Prefers Republican Party)  47921   47921       203954
8       (Prefers Republican Party)  125741  125741      73003
8       (Prefers Democratic Party)  73003   125741      73003
9       (Prefers Democratic Party)  118132  48662       118132
9       (Prefers Republican Party)  48662   48662       118132
10      (Prefers Democratic Party)  99279   82213       99279
10      (Prefers Republican Party)  82213   82213       99279
```

That's fine, as far as it goes, and I can add selector column and select by that:

```
CongressMargins <- CongressTidy  %>%
  group_by(Dist) %>%
  mutate(GOPVotes = sum(ifelse(Party == "(Prefers Republican Party)", Votes, 0))) %>%
  mutate(DemVotes = sum(ifelse(Party == "(Prefers Democratic Party)", Votes, 0))) %>%
  mutate(selector = c(1,2)) %>%
  subset(selector == 1, select = c(Dist, GOPVotes, DemVotes))
```

Which gives me what I want, and I can calculate the Margin just fine from there:

```
Dist    GOPVotes    DemVotes
<fctr>  <dbl>       <dbl>
1       101428      124151      
2       79518       122173      
3       124796      78018       
4       153079      0       
5       135470      87772       
6       83025       141265      
7       47921       203954      
8       125741      73003       
9       48662       118132      
10      82213       99279
```

But if there are 2 unopposed races that would get screwed up, because it's based on vector recycling. And it's just ugly. And **there's gotta be a better way.** Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can calculate the group sum first and then spread. If you want the missing cell to be 0, use `spread(Party, Votes, fill = 0)`.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(Dist, Party) %>%
  summarise(Votes = sum(Votes)) %>%
  spread(Party, Votes) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2
# # A tibble: 10 x 3
#     Dist `(Prefers Democratic Party)` `(Prefers Republican Party)`
#    <int>                        <int>                        <int>
#  1     1                       124151                       101428
#  2     2                       122173                        79518
#  3     3                        78018                       124796
#  4     4                           NA                       153079
#  5     5                        87772                       135470
#  6     6                       141265                        83025
#  7     7                       203954                        47921
#  8     8                        73003                       125741
#  9     9                       118132                        48662
# 10    10                        99279                        82213
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Dist    Party                       Votes
1       '(Prefers Democratic Party)'  124151
                  1       '(Prefers Republican Party)'  101428
                  2       '(Prefers Democratic Party)'  122173
                  2       '(Prefers Republican Party)'  79518
                  3       '(Prefers Republican Party)'  124796
                  3       '(Prefers Democratic Party)'  78018
                  4       '(Prefers Republican Party)'  75307
                  4       '(Prefers Republican Party)'  77772
                  5       '(Prefers Republican Party)'  135470
                  5       '(Prefers Democratic Party)'  87772
                  6       '(Prefers Democratic Party)'  141265
                  6       '(Prefers Republican Party)'  83025
                  7       '(Prefers Democratic Party)'  203954
                  7       '(Prefers Republican Party)'  47921
                  8       '(Prefers Republican Party)'  125741
                  8       '(Prefers Democratic Party)'  73003
                  9       '(Prefers Democratic Party)'  118132
                  9       '(Prefers Republican Party)'  48662
                  10      '(Prefers Democratic Party)'  99279
                  10      '(Prefers Republican Party)'  82213",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dcast` from `reshape2` package specifying the aggregation function as `sum`

```
 library(reshape2)
 dcast(dat,Dist~Party,sum,value.var = "Votes")


   Dist (Prefers Democratic Party) (Prefers Republican Party)
1     1                     124151                     101428
2     2                     122173                      79518
3     3                      78018                     124796
4     4                          0                     153079
5     5                      87772                     135470
6     6                     141265                      83025
7     7                     203954                      47921
8     8                      73003                     125741
9     9                     118132                      48662
10   10                      99279                      82213
```

Using base R:

```
xtabs(Votes~Dist+Party,dat)
    Party
Dist (Prefers Democratic Party) (Prefers Republican Party)
  1                      124151                     101428
  2                      122173                      79518
  3                       78018                     124796
  4                           0                     153079
  5                       87772                     135470
  6                      141265                      83025
  7                      203954                      47921
  8                       73003                     125741
  9                      118132                      48662
  10                      99279                      82213
```

The above output is of class `table` you can make it a dataframe by:

`as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(Votes~Dist+Party,dat))` Now this is a dataframe, you can subset the way you want